# Drawing more then 1 graphics on pictureBox1 with button_Click + mixed up graphics

Tags: c#, graphics, buttonclick

I am making an application on windows forms application. It is called a artgenerator.

The meaning of this application is that everytime that I click on a button for example button "ellipse" that an ellipse will be drawn on the form. Now everything is going smooth untill I press all three buttons after eachother. Then the application is combining all figures into 1. And that's not what I want. Also after I draw 1 ellipse, square or line and I press the same button again the graphic dissapear and a new one appear. How to fix these problems?

I will send my code down below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Kunstgenerator
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool TekenCirkel = false;
        bool TekenRechthoek = false;
        bool TekenLijn = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Hide();
        }

        private void btnCirkel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TekenCirkel = true;
            pictureBox1.Show();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }

        private void btnRechthoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TekenRechthoek = true;
            pictureBox1.Show();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }

        private void btnLijn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TekenLijn = true;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            pictureBox1.Show();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Refresh();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
                // Er wordt een Random aangemaakt.
                Random random = new Random();

                // Breedte en hoogte wordt aangemaakt en verwezen naar zichzelf.
                // Hier wordt de Random gebruikt om een willekeurige hoogte en breedte te maken.
                int width = random.Next(this.Width);
                int height = random.Next(this.Height);

                // Primaire kleuren Rood, Geel, Blauw worden hier aangemaakt.
                // Door de Random is de kleuren willekeurig. Er wordt een kleur uitgekozen tussen 1 en 255
                int r = random.Next(255);
                int g = random.Next(255);
                int b = random.Next(255);

            if (TekenRechthoek)
            {
                Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
                if (random.Next(2) == 0)
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)), width, height, width, height);
                }
                else
                {
                    graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))), width, height, width, height);
                } 

            }
            if (TekenLijn)
            {
                Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
                graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))), width, height, width, 100);
            }

            if (TekenCirkel)
            {
                Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;

                if (random.Next(2) == 0)
                {
                    graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)), width, height, width, height);
                }
                else
                {
                    graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))), width, height, width, height);
                }
            }
          }          
       }
   }
```

This is all the code. I put also a picture here below to show you guys what I mean with combining graphics.

[image]

One other thing. Because my size and location of the graphics are all random they all dissapear (half-ish) from the screen. Is this fixable or is this part of the random-ness?

Thanks in advance

Btw I am a beginner in programming

Comment: `that's not what I want` what **do** you want? hard to offer a solution without knowing that.

Comment: You are setting the new but not resetting the old graphic types.. Also: Read up on Enum!!

Comment: Consider using `enum` with a `switch()` statement instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your if statement to this:

```
if (TekenRechthoek)
{
}
else if ( TekenLijn )
{
}
else if ( TekenCirkel )
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks that brought me somewere. Now another thing :)
because of this I get a square if I click on the ellipse (ofcourse after I pressed square). So it looks like they are bounded to the other button once they have been clicked

thanks for reply though

Comment: Set the booleans to false once they are drawn

Comment: ye captain obvious. 

Thanks man :)

Any idea's about keeping graphics on picturebox? because of the random X and Y position it's all over the place (must be random) but preferable not falling out of the screen. Or is something like that innevetable when you work with randoms?

Comment: NO, only if you completely refuse to apply some basic Math.. Hint: You need to set the position first, then you can limit the range of allowable sizes..

Comment: You can draw everywhere you want, so you have to check the boundaries of the form. Dont have much exp with winforms drawing.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you want to happen as each button is pressed.  If it is one at a time, an easy way us to use `RadioButtons`.  Set the appearance to "Button" and they will act like toggle buttons - they stay down until another one is pressed.  Additionally, only one can be pressed at a time which sounds like what you want.

Then to track which shape to draw:

```
private enum Shapes
{
    Circle,
    Line,
    Rect
}

// current shape var with default val
private Shapes thisShape = Shapes.Circle;
```

Then just set the current shape to draw in each check changed event:

```
private void rbCircle_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbCircle.Checked) {
        thisShape = Shapes.Circle;
    }
}
```

When you click a different button, it will get set to that shape indicator.  Then draw the correct shape based on the value of `thisShape`.  Using 3 variables to track one image state will usually result in confusion.

Comment: Thanks for reply

I cannot use radio button even if it's better. I am in programming class and they want me to do this with buttons :(

any idea with the X and Y position? that the graphics will not fall off the screen or is that innevetable, because of the random?

Comment: a radio BUTTON is not a BUTTON?  It will even look just like one on screen using the `Appearance` property.

Comment: oh I don't know that much from the tools option. I got a paper from school that describes the assignment. They say must use "button" and we never used radio button

thanks for reply tough